# Book on theory of relations

Tags: relations

Could someone recommend an introductory book on Theory of Relations for undergraduate level mathematician? Something gentle and intuitive.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/933212/good-book-for-self-studying-binary-relations).